# Pandas Apply, Local Function with Dictionary Argument

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I've been struggling with this for a few days. I am trying to vectorize some parts of a code -- which so far is working tremendously. However, the biggest calculation is a call to a local function which uses a list of dictionaries as arguments.

The dictionaries are simply functions of the row, so at first I tried to put the dictionaries as new columns in the dataframe. I was hoping I could simply create a column with dict type and insert the entire dictionary into each row. No dice there.

Now, I'm just trying to create the dictionary as part of the function call, but running into issues.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

def somefunc(d):
    return d['key']+5

df['C'] = df.apply(somefunc, d={'key':df['A']}, axis=1)
```

I am getting an error of `TypeError: somefunc() got multiple values for argument 'd'`.

For some of my other functions, I wrote a "helper" function, which would take individual values from the row and create the dictionaries before sending them to the actual calculation function, but this final one needs to stay a little more flexible.

Looking around for issues with argument count, I tried a slightly different approach where I pass in the row (apparently be using the axis=1 argument)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

def somefunc(row,d):
    row['C'] = d['key']
    return row

d = {'key' : 10}

new_df = df.apply(somefunc, axis=1, args=({'key' : df['A']},))
```

This one gets closer. It does not throw an error, but produces `Name: A, dtype:int64` as the value for the "C" columns. If I create the dictionary statically first, and pass it in, it works fine, but obviously I need to create a unique dictionary for each row.

It's clear I don't fully understand how this apply() function works. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
def somefunc(d):
    return d['A'] + 5


df['C'] = df.apply(somefunc, axis=1)
```

But you don't need `apply` at all, use broadcasting

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + 5
```

`df`

```
   A  B  C
0  1  4  6
1  2  5  7
2  3  6  8
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by using `lambda`. This approach makes more sense to me for some reason. The lambda operator clearly tells me it's a row, and I don't seem to have any problem creating a dictionary using row data in the function call itself.

Example below is a working example of what I am trying to do. I just worry if using lambda is slower than not.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

def somefunc(a, d):
    #row['C'] = d['key']
    return a * d['key']

#d = {'key' : 10}

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: somefunc(x['A'], {'key' : x['B']}), axis=1)
df
```